# Solve non-linear set of three equations using scipy

Tags: python, nonlinear-equations, scipy

I need to solve a non-linear set of three equations using scipy.

However, I do not have any clue on which algorithm is suitable for my problem from a mathematical point of view (stability, convergence behaviour), since scipy provides a huge variety of different algorithms in the [`scipy.optimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/optimize.html) module such as:

- [scipy.optimize.root](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html)
- [scipy.optimize.fsolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html)
- [nonlinear solvers](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.nonlin.html)

Here is my non-linear set (two linear, and a non-linear) of equations with 3 unknown variables:

$$
Q(t_k)=m_Sc_S\left(\vartheta_S(t_k)-\vartheta_S(t_{k-1})\right)\\
Q(t_k)=\dot{m}_Gc_{pG}\big(\vartheta_{GE}-\vartheta_{GA}(t_{k})\big)\Delta t\\
Q(t_k)=A\alpha\frac{\big(\vartheta_S(t_k)-\vartheta_{GE}\big)-\big(\vartheta_S(t_k)-\vartheta_{GA}(t_k)\big)}{\ln{\left(\frac{\vartheta_S(t_k)-\vartheta_{GE}}{\vartheta_S(t_k)-\vartheta_GA(t_k)}\right)}}\Delta t
$$

where unknown variables are:

- $\vartheta_S(t_k)$
- $\vartheta_{GA}(t_k)$
- $Q(t_k)$

and

- $m_S = 6.868\,\mathrm{kg}$
- $\dot{m}_G = 0.007\,\mathrm{kg/s}$
- $c_S = 500\,\mathrm{J/kg K}$
- $c_{pG} = 1005\,\mathrm{J/kg K}$
- $\vartheta_S(0) = 273\,\mathrm{K}$
- $\vartheta_{GA}(0) = 293\,\mathrm{K}$
- $\vartheta_{GE} = 353\,\mathrm{K}$
- $A = 3.733\,\mathrm{m}^2$
- $\alpha = 99\,\mathrm{W/m}^2\mathrm{K}$
- $\Delta t = t_k-t_{k-1} = 1\,\mathrm{s}$

Which algorithm is probably the best one for my problem?

Comment: What is $t_{k-1}$? Is there some sort of initial condition for the $Q(0)$?

Comment: $t_{k-1}$ just symbolizes the time dependence of the temperatures $\vartheta_{foo}$ whereas $k-1$ means that this references to the value of the last calculation / discretization step resp. initial condition if we talk about the first step. I am not sure, but $Q(0)$ should be zero, since there is no heat transfered at init.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but your last equation shows $t_k=1$, so you should either remove it or provide something about the size of the time steps.

Comment: @BillBarth: Since this is part of a self-written simulation software the step size depends on the number of discretisation elements specified by the user. In the simulation algorithm I converted the rotation of a wheel into time steps depending on the total number of discretisation points. Due to simplicity I assumed that the step width is equal to one second which is given if the wheel turns with 1 rpm and is represented by 360 discretisation segments / points. If you wish having a more physical approach I could add the appropiate units to all variables.

Comment: OK, replacing $t_k$ by $\Delta t$ makes this a bit clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your problem is small, you're probably best off trying `fsolve` or `root`. Both of these are interfaces to MINPACK and call `HYBRD` or `HYBRJ`. Since calculating a Jacobian matrix for your system shouldn't be hard (either do it by hand, or use your favorite computer algebra system, like SymPy, Sage, Maple, or Mathematica), you should supply a Jacobian matrix. The `HYBR` functions in MINPACK use "Powell's hybrid method", which uses Newton's method and checks if Newton steps will be descent steps by comparing against least-squares minimization (specifically, does the Newton step also decrease the sum-of-squared-residuals). If Newton steps are not descent steps, then it falls back to the gradient of the sum-of-squared-residuals.

I think you're probably better off ignoring all of the alternatives for now. All of these other alternatives, broadly speaking, try to find low-dimensional structure in high-dimensional problems. Your problem has dimension 3, so the comparative savings of finding lower-dimensional structure aren't that great compared to, say, PDE discretizations that might have tens of thousands of variables.

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but I am curious roughly speaking, how are the residuals in the least squares calculated? I understand how when fitting parameters to data, you have residuals between the model and exp, and you tweak parameters to minimize the sum of residuals... but in a  X equations X unknowns, with no data to use to compare the model with, what are the residuals?

Answer (score 2):

`scipy.optimize.root` is a unified interface for the nonlinear solvers that you list in your third point, which are implemented in Python. On the other hand, `scipy.optimize.fsolve` is a wrapper around some Fortran functions (see docs). The interface is the same for both and I haven't seen any benchmarks (quick Google search), so just implement the function of the system and give them a go. Focus on correct implementation of this function and on choosing a sensible initial condition and then just try both `root` with its different methods and `fsolve`.